# algorithm that finds the element ai in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search-tree, sequence

A sequence ***A=[a1, a2,...,an]*** is a valley sequence, if there's an index **i** with **1 < i < n**  such that:

```
a1 > a2 > .... > ai
```

and

```
ai < ai+1 < .... < an.
```

It is given that a valley sequence must contain at least three elements in it.

What i'm really confused about is, how do we find an algorithm that finds the element **ai**, as described above, in  ***O(log n)***  time? 
Will it be similar to an  ***O(log n)***  binary search?

And if we do have a binary search algorithm which find an element of an array in  ***O(log n)***  time, can we improve the runtime to  ***O(log log n)*** ?

Comment: This problem is similar to the Rotated Sorted Array problem. Here is the link to geeksforgeeks solution to it. 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-element-in-a-sorted-and-rotated-array/

Comment: @Nishit thanks!! i had a look at the link. it helped :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a BIG-O(*logn*) algorithm, we will have to reduce the problem size by half in constant time.

In this problem specifically, we can select a mid-point, and check if its slope is increasing, decreasing or a bottom.

- If the slope is increasing, the part after the mid-point could be ignored
- else if the slope is decreasing, the part before the mid-point could be ignored
- else the mid-point should be the bottom, hence we find our target.

Java code example :

Input: [99, 97, 89, 1, 2, 4, 6], output: 1

```
public int findBottomValley(int[] valleySequence) {
    int start = 0, end = valleySequence.length - 1, mid;

    while (start + 1 < end) {
        mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

        if (checkSlope(mid, valleySequence) < 0) {
            // case decreasing
            start = mid;
        } else if (checkSlope(mid, valleySequence) > 0) {            
            // case increasing
            end = mid;
        } else {
            // find our target
            return valleySequence[mid];
        }
    }

    // left over with two points
    if (valleySequence[start] < valleySequence[end]) {
        return valleySequence[start];
    }
    return valleySequence[end];
}
```

The helper function `checkSlope(index, list)` will check the slope at the index of the list, it will check three points including index - 1, index and index + 1. If the slope is decreasing, return negative numbers; if the slope is increasing, return positive numbers; if the numbers at index - 1 and index + 1 are both larger than the number at index, return 0;

Note: the algorithm makes assumptions that:

- the list has at least three items
- the slope at the adjacent elements cannot be flat, the reason behind this is that if there are adjacent numbers that are equal, then we are unable to decide which side the bottom is. It could appear at the left of such flat slope or on the right, hence we will have to do a linear search.

Since random access of an array is already constant O(1), having an O(*logn*) access time may not help the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks @Jaiwei!! Really appreciated the approach.
Quick question tho: how do we prove the correctness of this algorithm?

Comment: @ArsalAbbas We could prove by induction. For this question, first, we assume the answer is in the given sequence. The base case is the size of the given list is 3, and our algorithm returns the correct answer. Then we prove the induction step. We assume the algorithm is correct when size N. And when the size of the list is N + 1, for the three different cases, our algorithm reduces the problem to a similar but smaller problem, and the correct answer is still in the sub list. Hence we conclude our algorithm is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that works a lot like binary search. Set a = 2 and b = n - 1. At each step, we will only need to consider candidates with index k such that a <= k <= b. Compute m = (a + b) / 2 (integer divide, so round down) and then consider array elements at indices m - 1, m and m + 1. If these elements are decreasing, then set a = m and keep searching. If these elements are increasing, then set b = m and keep searching. If these elements form a valley sequence, then return m as the answer. If b - a < 2, then there is no valley.

Since we halve the search space each time, the complexity is logarithmic. Yes, we access three elements and perform two comparisons at each stage, but calculation will show that just affects constant factors.

Note that this answer depends on these sequences being strictly decreasing and then increasing. If consecutive elements can repeat, the best solution is linear in the worst case.

Just saw the second part. In general, no, a way to find specific elements in logarithmic time - even constant time - is useless in general. The problem is that we really have no useful idea what to look for. If the spacing of all elements' values is greater than their spacing in the array - this isn't hard to arrange - then I can't see how you'd pick something to search for.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Patrick87. It really helped.
The algorithm that you provided, does it have a O(n) runtime? I got the algorithm but I am still a little confused about the runtime.

Also, about the second part of my question, I am still not sure how I can find an element in O(log log n) time. Your answers was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @ArsalAbbas (1) It is O(log n) time since it halves the search space each iteration. (2) Being able to find an element in O(log n) time does not help us since, in general, we have no useful idea what to look for.